# Property '_json' is private in type 'Message' but not in type

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-pubsub

If I try

```
import type { Message } from 'firebase-functions/v1/pubsub'

const data = 'base64 string'

const message = {
  data,
  attributes: {},
  /** @hidden */
  _json: vi.fn(),
  json: vi.fn(),
  toJSON: vi.fn(),
} satisfies Message
```

I get

> Type '{ data: string; attributes: {}; _json: Mock<any, any>; json: Mock<any, any>; toJSON: Mock<[], any>; }' does not satisfy the expected type 'Message'.
> Property '_json' is private in type 'Message' but not in type '{ data: string; attributes: {}; _json: Mock<any, any>; json: Mock<any, any>; toJSON: Mock<[], any>; }'.

If I try to instantiate the class

```
import { Message } from 'firebase-functions/v1/pubsub'

const message = new Message(data)

console.log(message)
```

I get data undefined.

> Message { data: undefined, attributes: {}, _json: undefined }

These APIs from Google Cloud are a pain; what can I do to get the right type on TypeScript?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Workaround

```
class MyMessage extends Message {
  constructor(public data: string) { super(data) }
}
```